# Not conform to protocol -- Swift

Tags: swift

I'm using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4.

When I'm trying to implement delegate method didSelectCountry, I get the error:

```
Type 'MBRegisterTableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'CountryPickerViewDelegate'
```

but I already have

```
func countryPickerView(_ countryPickerView: CountryPickerView, didSelectCountry country: Country) {}
```

Protocol declaration:

```
public protocol CountryPickerViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
/// Called when the user selects a country from the list.
func countryPickerView(_ countryPickerView: CountryPickerView, didSelectCountry country: Country)
```

}

Xcode offers to use stub, but it doesn't help at all. 
Silly question, but I'm stuck.

[ViewController](https://gist.github.com/antonkashpor/d0bbde67d89444e7a26f1b4304e97d1e)
[Protocol declaration](https://gist.github.com/antonkashpor/7245812b1b726f637662547dd9b5e697)

**Update**: Ok, that was a bug of Xcode. It works fine as should be. It has wrong class reference through the whole project.

Comment: @Krunal https://gist.github.com/antonkashpor/d0bbde67d89444e7a26f1b4304e97d1e

Comment: Can you show your class declaration line ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code; show the protocol declaration and your implementation of the protocols functions.

Comment: ... and the full error message from the log navigator. That usually gives a hint which protocol method (the compiler thinks) is missing.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've updated with gist-links.

Comment: **edit your question to include the relevant code**. Do not link to your code.

Comment: Please ask questions with relevant code next time.

Answer (score 2):

From the gist you have posted I see that you have an empty extension for the extension 'CountryPickerViewDelegate'. You will need to implement all CountryPickerViewDelegate protocol's methods in that extension. If that protocol for example has 1 method named

```
countryPickerView(_ countryPickerView: CountryPickerView, didSelectCountry country: Country) -> Void
```

you would need to implement something like the following

```
extension MBRegisterTableViewController: CountryPickerViewDelegate {

  func countryPickerView(_ countryPickerView: CountryPickerView, didSelectCountry country: Country) {
    //Do something here with the selected country

  }

}
```

After that build your project again. Sometimes Xcode gets stuck and report an error up until you do a clean and re-build.

Hope that helps

Comment: the protocol has 1 method. I've implemented it properly.

Comment: I suggest you update the question with your latest code and error and update the gists you have linked. On the gists you don't seem to have implemented the protocol at all

Comment: Sorry, wrong file. I've updated the latest code.

Comment: Try to declare the protocol as class maybe? I just tried your CountryPickerViewDelegate and implemented in my project and worked fine

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is the same that I already have in the code. Please, delete your answer and I will be able to close my answer. Because, nobody knows how to resolve the issue, but everybody can downvote.

Comment: George? I've update. It's just the bug